# CSS percentage values higher than 100%

Tags: html, css, standards, percentage

Layering a file input field over a button with a box-shadow, i found myself wanting to use 110% height on the input, so that it also covers the shadow part.

It works fairly well.

**But:** Is this correct, legal and valid CSS according to standards?

Comment: Validity of percentages aside, wouldn't it have been better in this particular case to remove the button's box shadow with some clever CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Testing percentages higher than 100% in the CSS validator gave me no validation errors, so it should be ok, see for yourself:
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator

Sometimes I define containers with 200% width so I can animate fluid divs across the screen, and have not encountered any issues with this so far.

I would still test it in all browsers you wish to support if I were you, but this applies to anything that has to do with web development of course.

Comment: Good idea trying the validator! I think that covers it.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#value-def-percentage percentage values are always relative to another value, so it should be safe to use any percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Percentages over 100% do validate just fine on [the W3C validation service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). I'd say you're good to go.